# HyperV WMI v2 How to wait for method to finish

Tags: c#, wmi, hyper-v

I use the "new" `System.Management.Infrastructure` library and I want to execute some methods. 
The result of the method down below is 4096 which means that the Job has started. 
How do I wait until or check whether it has changed to 0? I have the same problem with applying, deleting and creating snapshots.

Is there a general way to check the "status"?

```cs
public async Task RequestStateChange(PublicServerInfo publicServer, string action)
{
    CimSession session = GetCimSession(publicServer.HostName);
    CimInstance vm = session.QueryInstances(hvNamespace, "WQL", "SELECT * FROM Msvm_ComputerSystem WHERE Name='" + publicServer.MachineID + "'").FirstOrDefault();
    CimMethodParametersCollection parameters = new CimMethodParametersCollection();
    if (action.ToLower() == "start")
    {
        parameters.Add(CimMethodParameter.Create("RequestedState", (UInt16)2, CimFlags.In));
    }
    else if (action.ToLower() == "shutdown")
    {
        parameters.Add(CimMethodParameter.Create("RequestedState", (UInt16)4, CimFlags.In));
    }

    CimMethodResult result = session.InvokeMethod(hvNamespace, vm, "RequestStateChange", parameters);
}
```